# Required HTML select element with chosen: Browser hint position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have a HTML form with a `<select>` element which is pimped by Chosen 1.4.2 and now is also marked as `required` (the new attribute which is defined by HTML 5).

If nothing is selected when the form is submitted, the browser shows a hint to select a value.  However, since the original `<select>` element is replaced by Chosen, the hint is shown not right below the selection control but *(Firefox)* in the upper left corner of the screen - where it can be missed easily in my case - or *(MSIE, Opera)* not at all.

Is there way to rectify this, e.g.

- by having Chosen handle some "validation" event of the replaced `<select>` control
- by preserving the original position of the replaced element and thus have the browser hint appear near the `Chosen` artifact
- other possibilities?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As of Chosen 1.5.0, there still doesn't seem to be built-in support for this situation, but based on [the discussion for issue 515](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/515) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hq7b426j/1/), I created a `chosen-patch.js` with the following content:

```
// "required" support for Chosen; see https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/515, http://jsfiddle.net/hq7b426j/1/
$.fn.oldChosen = $.fn.chosen
$.fn.chosen = function (options) {
  var select = $(this),
      is_creating_chosen = !!options;

  if (is_creating_chosen && select.css('position') === 'absolute') {
    // if we are creating a chosen and the select already has the appropriate styles added
    // we remove those (so that the select hasn't got a crazy width), then create the chosen
    // then we re-add them later
    select.removeAttr('style');
  }

  var ret = select.oldChosen(options)

  // only act if the select has display: none, otherwise chosen is unsupported (iPhone, etc)
  if (is_creating_chosen && select.css('display') === 'none') {
    // https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/515#issuecomment-33214050
    // only do this if we are initializing chosen (no params, or object params) not calling a method
    select.attr('style', 'display:visible; position:absolute; clip:rect(0,0,0,0)');
    select.attr('tabindex', -1);
  }
  return ret
}
```

I include this right after including `chosen.jquery[.min].js` and before my code which activates it.  I tried it with Chosen 1.5.0 (jQuery version) and the browsers Firefox, Opera and IE 11.

There is no red frame around the `required` selection control, but the hint is properly placed.

Comment: This is brilliant! I don't know why, but this works. The HTML5 validation "hint" (as OP calls it) is correctly positioned under the select. This also respects tab order (other solutions mess that up). So thank you, Tobias. You are a true hero.